# Downloading a war using repository connector

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to download a war from a nexus repo, so I am trying to use this plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin

[image]
[image]

I have made sure that the repo url is correct and contain the needed war file.

When I build, I get the following error

`class org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Specified destination directory cannot be created: /usr/share/maven-repo/mygroup/myartifact/myversion`

I have give write permissions to all users for this directory `/usr/share/maven-repo`

Comment: Talking about all the users, have you provided write access to the Jenkins user too?

Comment: When I run the command `id`, it tells me the user is `ubuntu`. I have given write access to Ubuntu.

Comment: Which user is running your Jenkins job? Plus check who is the owner of `/usr/share/maven-repo`